# How to move from Activity to Fragment from onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new in Fragment  activity and my situation is i have implemented payment gateway and successfully got result on Activity. My confirmation activity is in fragment so when i received result from payment gateway in activity  result in onActivityResult after success or failed condition of PG how to transfer to confirmationFragment 
I am using `android.app.Fragment;` 
and my code of PaymentActivity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.PAYU_SDK_PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE) {





        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Success - Payment ID : " + data.getStringExtra(SdkConstants.PAYMENT_ID));
            String paymentId = data.getStringExtra(SdkConstants.PAYMENT_ID);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "failure");
            showDialogMessage("cancelled");
        } else if (resultCode == PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.RESULT_FAILED) {
            Log.i("app_activity", "failure");

            if (data != null) {
                if (data.getStringExtra(SdkConstants.RESULT).equals("cancel")) {

                } else {
                    showDialogMessage("failure");
                }
            }
            //Write your code if there's no result
        } else if (resultCode == PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.RESULT_BACK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "User returned without login");
            showDialogMessage("User returned without login");
        }
    }
}
```

In this above code i have some condition so according to these condition i have to move fragment.

and i have some confrimationFragments. I hope you understand or give me better way to do

My main Activity code

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new BuyActivity();

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new SaleFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new MoneyFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            //fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            //History
            fragment = new HistoryFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            //about
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: use appv4.Fragment

Comment: if im using App.v4.Fragment i have to change whole application

Comment: Then use INTERFACE or Event bus

Comment: @Divyesh i have no idea about this

Answer (score 2):

You must write onActivityResult() in your MainActivity.Java as follows

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

after this your `onActivityResult` in fragment is called.

Comment: Thanks @mehul but getChildFragmentManager() is "Cannot resolve method" coz im using  android.app.Fragment

Comment: Then you have to change android.app.Fragment to app.fragment vs v4.app.fragment. and getChildFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager();